# How to add tasks entry to taskbar with Delphi 4?

Tags: delphi, delphi-4

How to add [tasks entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460(v=vs.85).aspx#tasks) to Win 7 application taskbar (right clicking menu) with Delphi 4 ?

I cannot change the project from Delphi 4 to newer but need to add Win 7 taskbar support.

Comment: Declare the COM interfaces and call them. You should be able to find existing Delphi translations of the COM interfaces with a bit of web search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These new APIs and capabilities are provided in the form of COM interfaces. Clearly these interfaces are not provided with stock Delphi 4, dating as it does from the 20th century. So to make progress you will need to define the interfaces you need, and use them as you would any other COM interface.

It seems very likely to me that a web search will yield a variety of Delphi definitions for these interfaces. I expect that the JEDI project, for instance, will have translations. You will very likely need to adapt these translations to compile in Delphi 4, but starting from pre-existing modern Delphi translations will likely be the quickest way to get this done. Be sure to keep one eye on the MSDN documentation as you go.